# How to sort xml elements by value with xslt

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an xml below.

```
<parent>
<child1>False</child1>
<child2>True</child2>
<child3>False</child3>
<child4>True</child4>
</parent>

<parent>
<child4>False</child1>
<child5>True</child2>
<child3>False</child3>
<child4>False</child4>
</parent>
```

After sorting by True the xml and the final xml should look like

```
<parent>
<child4>True</child4>
<child2>True</child2>
<child1>False</child1>
<child3>False</child3>
</parent>
<parent>
<child5>True</child2>
<child4>False</child1>
<child3>False</child3>
<child4>False</child4>
</parent>
```

Can it be done with xslt. I need xslt logic to sort the xml elements by True.

Comment: Just to add, the child element may have attributes as well.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Is it XSLT 1 or 2? You've included both tags.

Comment: Other than putting the "True" elements first, do you care about order?  For example, in your first parent element, do you care if child4 comes before child2 or is the other way around acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xsl:sort` is what you're looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="parent">
  <parent>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="." order="descending"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </parent>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the above xslt is not working when I run the sample in the post

Comment: @storia321 - What does "is not working" mean? Works here: http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mP

Comment: @storia321 Are you wrapping your parent elements in an outer element?  Because it will not work on the exact example you've posted as that is not valid xml (there can only be one top-level element).